# I cant display the images from jfreechart in my application

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, jfreechart

I need to display images in my application. I am working with jfreechart and Spring Framework. It has been several days but i can not resolve the problem. When i execute the code I get a page with text like [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWbAR.jpg) but not the page i was expecting with the chart!

Tha images actually exists . As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T60vu.jpg) i could access to another image in the same folder. What is more strange is that when i right click in the space where the image should be and open it in another tab it actually appears!!! as you can see[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRg4v.jpg)

This is my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/recursosHumanos/dashboardRrhh"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)

public String dashboardRrhh(Model mapa, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String adminLineChart = createLineCharts(req, res);

    mapa.addAttribute("adminLineChart", adminLineChart);

    return "recursosHumanos/dashboardRrhh";

}

private String createLineCharts( HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String file = "";

    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

    List<Usuario> listadoDeUsuarios = us.encontrarTodos();

    dataset.addValue(5, "Resignation", "2010");
    dataset.addValue(10, "Resignation", "2011");
    dataset.addValue(8, "Resignation", "2012");
    dataset.addValue(10, "Resignation", "2013");
    dataset.addValue(7, "Resignation", "2014");
    dataset.addValue(8, "Resignation", "2015");

    JFreeChart grafico = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
            "Ingresos de Personal", 
            "Años", 
            "Cantidad de Empleados", 
            dataset, 
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, 
            true, 
            true, 
            false);

    grafico.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
    final TextTitle subtitulo = new TextTitle("El grafico muestra la distribucion de la tasa de Despidos");
    subtitulo.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    grafico.addSubtitle(subtitulo);

    ChartRenderingInfo info = null;

    System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", "C:\\Users\\Pisner-Lichtenstein\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\com.gambbate.faqu\\src\\main\\webapp\\static\\css\\charts");

    info = new ChartRenderingInfo(new StandardEntityCollection());
    HttpSession session = req.getSession();
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

    try {
        file = ServletUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(grafico, 700, 300, info, session);

        ChartUtilities.writeImageMap(out, "imgMap", info, false);
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException iOException) {
        iOException.printStackTrace();
    }



    String fileName = req.getContextPath() + "/recursosHumanos/grafico?filename=" + file;

    return fileName;

}
```

and this is my JSP

```
    <%-- 
    Document   : recursosHumanos
    Created on : 26-jun-2016, 20:01:34
    Author     : Marcelo
    --%>

    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="windows-1252"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-
 1252">
        <title>Gambbate - faqu Soft</title>    
        <link href="<c:url value='/static/css/principal.css' /> "     
     rel='stylesheet' />
        <link href="<c:url value='/static/css/bootstrap.min.css' /> " 
    rel='stylesheet' />
        <link href="<c:url value='/static/css/font-awesome.min.css' /> " 
    rel='stylesheet' />

    </head>

    <body>

        <%@include file="../barraSuperior.jsp" %>

        <img id="logoG" src="<c:url value='/static/css/images/GambbateIcon.jpg' 
    /> " />

        <img src="<c:url value='/static/css/charts/${adminLineChart}' /> " 
    width="200" height="200" >

        <img src="${adminLineChart}" border=0 usemap="#imgMap" >

        <script src="<c:url value='/static/js/jquery.min.js' /> "></script>
        <script src="<c:url value='/static/js/bootstrap.min.js' /> "></script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Can you verify 1. if the chart image is stored at correct path. 2. If you can access any other static resource from that folder.

Comment: @ZakiAnwarHamdani thanks so much for your help and guide. Unfortunately it didnt work. The image actually exist and i can access othe resources form that folder. What is more strange as you can see in the image that i added to the post is that when i make a right click on the empty space and open the image in another tab i can actually see it!!!

Comment: Well, that means something wrong with your html. Try to debug in browser for any errors.